# Начала появляться ошибка net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

На серверах стоит wildcard сертификат letsencrypt *site.ru, site.ru. На server.site.ru залиты видео, которые отдаются на site.ru. Несколько дней назад у некоторых пользователей перестали грузится видео с ошибкой в браузере net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID. В консоли браузера на server.site.ru в security ошибка No security information No security details are available for this origin. Никто не сталкивался?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/news/t/580818/

Comment: Спасибо, что интересно, с основным сайтом проблемы нет.